# Does C++ allow function to call itself with insufficient parameters?

Tags: c++

I know the question sounds ridiculous, but i need confirmation from experts here, so pls let me explain the situation:

I am debugging a C++ code (quite long, ~5000 lines), and i found something strange, which i tried to simplify as follows:

```
myClass.h
class myclass
{
  ...
  void myfun(int p1, int p2, mytype *p3, bool isFirstTime);
  ...
}
=================================================================
myClass.cpp
...
void myclass::myfun(int p1, int p2, mytype *p3, bool isFirstTime)
{
  ...
  if (mycond[y] == false)
  {
    myarr[y] = p1;
    myfun(y, y, p3);   <--- here no bool parameter given     (*)
  }
  ...
}
...
```

The code can be compiled and run without any error or warning (for function `myfun`). But since there are many `if-else` within the code, i am not sure if the command at line `(*)` is actually called during the process or not.

So the question is: This line is used correctly or not? If correct, please explain me or give me some information about this "type" of function. If not correct, why there is no warning or error while compiling?

Comment: If you simply constructed a minimal testcase you'd immediately see the answer.

Comment: This construct definitely does not compile. You haven't posted all the code. Make your example as small as you can, and post it here (in the process of doing this, you will probably find the problem yourself).

Comment: thanks all. My question is solved. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the function doesn't have a default parameter, e.g.

```
void f(int x, int y, int z = 0) // we can call inside f(1,2) since z is a default parameter
```

then NO, it cannot call itself with less parameters. However, it can call an overloaded version with less parameters:

```
void f(int x, int y); // one version
void f(int x, int y, int z); // another overload, this can call the first overload f(1,2)
```

So check your code for either default parameters or overloaded versions. Also, default parameters should go in the header file, the implementation file does not have to specify them again.

Comment: you meant only in header file it must be `f(..., bool etc = false)`, and in .ccp file it's just `f(..., bool etc)`?

Comment: @scmg yes, exactly. In fact, if you try to specify the default param. in the .cpp file, you'll get *error: redefinition of ...*

Comment: ok, sounds logic. This function in header file is `f(... bool etc = false)`. It's called during the process with `f(..., true)`. Then which value `etc` will take for the line `(*)`?

Comment: @scmg when you specify the third parameter, then the default is ignored. So in your case, `etc` will be `true`. Only if you don't specify it the default parameter will be used.

Comment: thanks, but pls enlighten me again: The `etc` will be true in the process's call since it's given in the process with `f(..., true)`, but the line `(*)` will take the 4th parameter as default (`etc = false`) since it's called without specifying `etc`?

Comment: if you call `f` with only 3 parameters, then `etc` will take its default value, i.e. `false`. If you call `f` with 4 parameters, then `etc` will take the value of the 4-th parameter, and the default value is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if myfun is overloaded. 
So, the function

```
myclass::myfun(int p1, int p2, mytype *p3);
```

needs to exists, but it's impossible to know that from your posted fragment.

Comment: i'm sure there is no overloaded version of the function. thanks anyway :-)